# How to get month and year from the date

Tags: vb6

How to get month & year from the date

```
Date = 01/02/2012 (dd/mm/yyyy)
```

From the above date, i want to get `02/2012 (mm/yyyy)`

How to write a code in vb6

Need vb6 code help

Comment: Haven't we been through this all before Gopal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Format$`:

```
Dim formattedDate as String
Dim myDate as Date

myDate = #1/2/2012#
formattedDate = Format$(myDate, "mm/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `Month()` and `Year()` functions which would take a Date parameter.

I.e. `Month(Now)` would return the Month and `Year(Now)` would return the Year.

```
Dim yourDate As Date
yourDate = #01/02/2012#

Dim yourMonth As Integer
Dim yourYear As Integer
yourMonth = Month(yourDate)
yourYear = Year(yourDate)
```

Comment: Literal date values should be enclosed in pound signs, i.e. `Dim yourDate As Date = #01/02/2012#`. Otherwise, declare yourDate as `String` and use `CDate` to change the string value to a date.

Comment: Thank you @Deanna. I got distracted by the date type formatting and forgot that you cannot both declare and provide an initial value to a variable on the same line in VB6.